# if else statement in bash

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

i want to let the user Input the selection, then use if elif statement to differentiate the input.

code:

```
read in

if $in = "1"
then 
Type="Employee1"
elif $in = "2"
then
Type="Employee2"
elif $in = "3"
then
Type="Employee3"
else
echo "Wrong input"
```

Error:

```
./Pay.sh: line 127: 1: command not found
./Pay.sh: line 130: 1: command not found
./Pay.sh: line 133: 1: command not found
Wrong input
```

please advise thank you

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Have you at least read a few things about bash before asking your question? you know, basic things like tests?

Comment: Read about the `select` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Square brackets are required.

```
if [[ $in = "1" ]]; then
    Type="Employee1"
elif [[ $in = "2" ]]; then
    Type="Employee2"
elif [[ $in = "3" ]]; then
    Type="Employee3"
else
    echo "Wrong input"
fi
```

For this particular chain of `if`s you might alternatively use a `case` statement.

```
case $in in
    1) Type='Employee1';;
    2) Type='Employee2';;
    3) Type='Employee3';;
    *) echo 'Wrong input' >&2;;
esac
```

Comment: Double square brackets are a more recent shell addition and are not universally portable.

Comment: The question is tagged `bash`, so `[[` is better than `[`.

Comment: Which doesn't change the fact that noting the possible portability issues is a good thing. I didn't suggest he not use them or vote him down for doing so or anything like that.

Answer (score 2):

This is the kind of cases for which `case` was built:

```
#!/bin/bash

read in

case "$in" in
        1)
           Type="Employee1"
           ;;
        2)
           Type="Employee2"
           ;;
        3)
           Type="Employee3"
           ;;
        *)
           echo "wrong input"
           ;;
esac

echo "type is $Type"
```

As a side note, with `case` you can match many conditions all together. For example, for `$in` being `1` or `5`:

```
case "$in" in
        1|5)
           Type="Employee1"
           ;;
```

Comment: `case "$in" in [1-3])`, perhaps?

Comment: What do you mean, @kojiro?

Comment: I'm suggesting a different pattern for your latter case statement.

Comment: Well, `1|5` stands for: `case $in=1 or `case $in=5`, so it would be a different situation. Thanks anyway, `[1-4]` would work if we wanted to check if the value belongs to the 1-4 range.

Comment: Yes, except `case $in in 1|5)…` won't actually match what OP is doing.

Comment: Yes, I know, it was a side note to provide more information about the `case` command... will update to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion it's poor style to use a shell keyword such as `in` as a variable name.

```
read inp

case $inp in
  1) Type="Employee1";;
  2) Type="Employee2";;
  3) Type="Employee3";;
  *) echo "Wrong input";;
esac
```

You may also consider the `select` construct. Widely disliked for its rigid output, it's still useful for getting very specific input:

```
select Type in Employee{1,2,3}; do
  # Whatever you want to do with $Type
done
```

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf can, yes, should no.

Comment: What's wrong with `$in`? It has a dollar sign in front, it can't be confused for a keyword.

Comment: why shouldn't he? in bash, keywords and variables don't play in the same ball park.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Shell keywords don't *always* have a `$` in front of them. The `$` is an indicator for *expansion*, not naming. (And even in expansion, the dollar sign is not required to be used in arithmetic expression context.)

Comment: @kojiro: `in` is not recognized as a keyword in arithmetic expression context.

Comment: Who downvoted this answer??? it's a neat answer (apart from the first sentence that's just a matter of opinion).

Comment: @KeithThompson I stand by my suggestion not to use it. I would also recommend not using `read`, `for`, `while`, `if`, etc.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Not I. I agree, this is a good answer, not downvote-worthy.

Comment: @kojiro: Fair enough; it's a valid opinion that using keywords as variable names is poor style. But as far as I know, there's no actual ambiguity, and IMHO it's equally valid not to worry about it. (I didn't even notice the use of `in` in the OP's code.) I suggest your answer might be improved by acknowledging that using keywords as variable names doesn't cause the script to fail.

Answer (score 0):

A totally different approach, if your goal is to set a variable depending on user's input is to use an associative array. The benefit is that if your choices get many more, the large part of the code will be for defining this array (that can eventually be easily automated), and not in the conditional part:

```
declare -A ass=() # that's a cool variable name
ass[1]="Employee 1"
ass[2]="Employee 2"
ass[3]="Employee 3"

read in # I have no problems with a variable named 'in' ;)

if [[ -z ${ass[$in]} ]]; then
    echo "Wrong answer you banana!"
else
    Type=${ass[$in]}
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the user input as part of Type:

```
read inp

if ( [ $inp -ge 1 ] && [ $inp -le 3 ] )
then
    Type="Employee$inp"
else
    echo "wrong input"
fi
```